# Convert String into formated date

Tags: apex, date, datetime

I have a string like this :

```
10/12/1990
```

that is supposed to be a date.

I need to convert it into a date like that :

```
1990-12-10
```

How can I do that ?
I tried a lot of things like converting it into a datetime and trying to format it like 'yyyy-MM-dd' but I always got this error when I run the code :

> System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 10/12/1990

Comment: Have you tried using `Date.parse()`, if you're in a locale that uses the MM/DD/YYYY date format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do it yourself using String split?

```
    String myDate ='10/12/1990';
List<String> arrayDate = myDate.split('/');
String newDateFormat = arrayDate[2]+'-'+arrayDate[1]+'-'+arrayDate[0];

System.debug(newDateFormat);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was finally the easier way to resolve that !

Answer (score 2):

*If* you're located in an org that uses the MM/DD/YYYY date format, the `Date.parse()` method will do the hard work for you to convert your string into a Date instance. Then, you can use `DateTime.format()` to render the output format you desire. (Oddly, `DateTime` has more functionality than `Date` for this purpose).

```
Date myDate = Date.parse('10/12/1990');
System.debug(
    DateTime.newInstance(myDate, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)).format('YYYY-MM-dd')
);
```

Comment: It's a per-user setting, actually.

Comment: Doh. That makes this approach fragile. I wish there existed a `Date.parseFormat()`.